# Angular ngIF: take variable value as condition

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to bind inputs from the back side to the front and got a question: to avoid crazy parsing exercise, can I use an income variable as a condition for *ngIf instruction? Like this:

```
    <div *ngFor="let ban of banners">
        <div *ngIf="ban.view_condition">
            <a [href]="ban.url" target="_blank">
                <img [src]="ban.img_url" [alt]="ban.title">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In `ban.view_condition` I'm trying to pass something like:
`"(parameterN == true || size > 5)"`

So the idea is to pass from the backend the set of properties that I want to check and based on this result - display or not the banner. Main goal - avoid manual validation.

Example:
(that's what I reveive from back)
`ban.view_condition = "app.size==10||userName=='test'";`

Basically I want to take the value and get something like:
`*ngIf="app.size==10||userName=='test'"`
in the end.

Is it feasible?
Of course, I understand that all targeted properties need to be present in the component.
Thanks for any inputs or ideas!

Comment: What exactly would be the question here? This is one of the main use case for the `*ngIf` directive. To render elements conditionally.

Comment: yeah, but it doesn't work like this :(

Comment: it just checks if the value is present, but not the value itself

Comment: @Eugen Well, saying `*ngIf="..."` is the same as saying `if(...)`, it will accept an expression and evaluate it for truthyness. If you want to check the value for something other than truthyness, you need to do that manually. i.e. `*ngIf="ban.view_condition === 'show'"` etc.

Comment: yes, I understand. My idea is to pass the exprection (conditional) to the ngIf with the variable from the backend. So ban.view_condition will have the expression for evaluation

Comment: @Eugen Ah, then you need to evaluate it manually. I'd suggest creating a function to do that

Comment: my actual idea was to avoid that :D

Comment: @Eugen Can you give a more concrete example with your component and an example of a condition you want to check for? I think that determines what you will be able to do or not do. In other words, a complete minimal example to reproduce the problem you are having

Comment: yes, please see the question, I've updated with example

Comment: What is `app.size` and `userName` in your example? Are those properties of your component? calling a function that uses `eval(conditions)` seems to be the correct solution here based on what you want, but suggesting that kind of makes me cringe. It's a huge security liability and you have to be sure that everything is in scope

Comment: in this case, inside of the method (in the component), I will have to split the input string, take each input property + it's value and compare with existing values in the component and return true/false. My plan is to put required parameters (there are 3 values actually) in the component as public and avoid using methods to compute if it's true/false. You see the idea?

Comment: "avoid using methods to compute if it's true/false" This is not possible. The only way to manually evaluate a string as JS code is to use the `eval()` function, which is not available inline in the `*ngIf="..."` directive

Comment: thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend creating a function in the controller that determines whether the banner should be displayed.

However, if you still want to evaluate that string as actual code. You may use the `eval` function.

```
evaluate(condition: string) {
    // eval(condition) will evaluate javascript code and execute it.
    return eval(condition);
}
```

Also, you must ensure any properties in the condition actually exist. (valid javascript)

I would still argue this is not the best approach, and you should reconsider your design.

Comment: I def agree with @JhonRayo99 this is the best option you have, better you better change your design.

Comment: FYI this is a huge security liability and should not be used unless you are absolutely sure of what you're doing.

Comment: @Eugene, if you are retrieving the condition from the backend, why don't you simply return a boolean value?

Comment: @Eugene: Binding a function to a directive with default change detection strategy would cause the function to be invoked for each CD cycle. This might be negligible for smaller functions but would quickly lead to a performance overhead. This also doesn't look like clean design. You're creating a tight coupling b/n backend and frontend by using same variable names. Ideally the backend should evaluate the condition and should only return the resulting boolean

Comment: @MichaelD 100% agreed - this is not a solution, it's a hack to cover up bad code design. Classic case of an ["XY problem"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: @MichaelD I totally agree with you, but the person who is doing backend doesn't want to do the change...

Answer (score 0):

You can just call a method and evaluate dependening on your current ban item what the result should be.

```
<div *ngFor="let ban of banners">
        <div *ngIf="calculateShow(ban)">
            <a [href]="ban.url" target="_blank">
                <img [src]="ban.img_url" [alt]="ban.title">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

public calculateShow(ban: any){
//call backend
//decide if you wish to return true or false here
}
```

> Basically I want to take the value and get something like:
> *ngIf="app.size==10||userName=='test'" in the end.

Yes it is absolutely feasible, considering that app.size and username exist as fields on your .ts file

Comment: in this case I need to parse all data from ban and make a descision. My wish is to delegate descision to the page based on the variable value (see the question, I've updated)

Comment: in case if I pass from the backend : ban.view_condition = "hasValue()", I expect *ngIf to call this method in my component. If this method is not present , it should return an exception. With simple *ngIf="ban.view_condition" - it doesn't refer to the actual value of the income variable, only check if it's not null (probably) or present